# Surviving a temporary COM port disconnection in Python

Tags: windows-7, python-2.7, serial-port, arduino

When I unplug the USB/Arduino from my PC, the Python script from which this was removed crashes.

```
#The connection to the Arduino
ser = serial.Serial('COM19',9600)

#Not connected to Arduino before connection is made
connected = False

#Loop until the Arduino is connected
while not connected:
    serin = ser.read()
    connected = True

#Debug Arduino connection
if connected == True:
    pprint('connected to arduino')
```

I have tried to use a TRY/EXCEPT to insure the connection re-connects, but when the Arduino is plugged in again, it will not recognize the COM port until the computer has been reset.

```
from pprint import pprint
import time
import serial

while True:
    #The connection to the Arduino
    try:
        ardResponse = serial.Serial('COM19',9600)
    except IOError:
        connected = False
        pprint('Arduino not connected to COM3')
        time.sleep(10)
    continue
    serin = ser.read()
    connected = True
    pprint('Connected to Arduino')
    ser.write('1')
    while ser.read() == '1':
        ser.read()
    pprint ('Arduino has finished being flashed')

    ser.close()
    pprint('Connection closed')

    time.sleep(5)
```

Is this because the COM port stays open, so the script cannot reuse it? Is there a way to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a ser.close() in your except: block
then prompt the user to fix it, and hit enter before trying the ser.open() again.